# Styling html select and checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, html-select

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/XJKE9/) is the fiddle. I am trying to style the `<select>` and `<input id='checkbox'>` using CSS. I am currently using `select {background: #4a4a4a}` and it works, but I cannot get any other styles to work. The checkbox style doesn't work at all when using `input[type='checkbox'] {background: #4a4a4a}`

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>Hola</option>
    <option>Bonjour</option>
</select>
<input type='checkbox'>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #252525;
}
select {
    background: #4a4a4a;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
input[type='checkbox'] {
    background: #4a4a4a;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

JS:

```
none
```

## Edit

I have started a project where I am making my own not styleable form elements. For more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626205/form-elements-that-arent-styleable) question.

Comment: Colleague of mine wrote this [JQuery plugin](http://destinwebguru.com/smf/). It might work or be useful as a reference on the concept. There are other similar plugins too that a search would turn up.

Comment: @happyhuman About this jquery plugin, would you just use CSS to style it after using `$().styleMyForms();`?

Comment: Correct. It includes example CSS in the download. If you inspect the anchors the plugin replaces the form elements with you'll notice they all get the class .sf and an additional specific class for the element type... e.g. .sf-checkbox for checkboxes. I would copy the css in the example and tweak to my need. Don't copy all the css, just the portion pertaining to the style forms. Hope it helps.

Comment: @happyhuman With jquery plugins I never know how to style. I usually ask questions about it, but I don't want to risk losing the rep. Can you explain the css selectors for this?

Comment: You simply style the element in CSS. This plugin was written with the intent that the user would style the elements according to what they needed. Unlike other plugins which provide out-of-the-box styling. I've played around with a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4YqL/) using your example. Most if not all of the selectors you would need to style are present in the example css.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! if this was an answer, I would accept it and vote up!

Comment: Updated my answer below... Let me know if it's sufficient. Hope I helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Styling checkboxes**

Styling checkboxes is tricky and inconsistent across browsers. Here is pure CSS approach. It takes advantage of that when label and input are connected with an `id=` , clicking on the label activates the input box itself. No JavaScript needed there.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox">
<label for="my-checkbox">Checkbox label text 
   <span class="checkbox"></span>
</label>
```

**CSS**
Hide checkbox, style the `<span>` as you like. I've used a CSS sprite here.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label .checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 19px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url('ui-sprite.png') left -90px no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label .checkbox {
  background: url('ui-sprite.png') -30px -90px no-repeat;
}
```

**Styling select inputs**

I haven't found a simple working solution for this yet.
[Here is an article about a hack that seems to be on a good way.](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/)

Answer (score 1):

Given how every browser has its own rules and exceptions when it comes to input element styling, I tend to use things like http://uniformjs.com/ for consistent input styling. Slows things down on pages with thousands of input elements, but otherwise quite excellent.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style all form elements. Browsers tend to not allow you to style check-boxes and select boxes (As well as drop downs, radios, file uploads etc...). The general concept I have used before is to hide the actual element and use a replacement element such as a div to display to the user. That div can be styled to look and work the way you want. The tricky part and part most often missed is you have to actually change the state of the hidden form element when the user interacts with the mock element.

This is a [JQuery Plugin](http://destinwebguru.com/smf/) that will provide the above functionality. This plugin was written with the intent that the user would style the elements according to what they need. Here is an example [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4YqL/) that demonstrates the plugin and exposes the CSS selectors with some basic styling. Basic code below...

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <select>
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>Hola</option>
    <option>Bonjour</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').styleMyForms();
});
```

**CSS**

```
 body {
     background: #252525;
 }
 .sf {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     float: left;
 }
.sf-checkbox {
     top: 6px;
     margin-right: 5px;
     height: 15px;
     width: 15px;
     background: #fff;
     border: 1px solid #444;
     cursor: pointer;
     background: #4a4a4a;
     border-radius: 0px;
}
.sf-select {
     display: block;
     width: 220px;
     border: 1px solid #222;
     background: #4a4a4a;
     border-radius: 0px;
     padding: 0px 10px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #333;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
.sf-select-wrap {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}
.sf-select-ul {
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 33px;
}
.sf-select-ul li {
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 0px 10px;
     color: #333;
 }
.sf-select-ul li:hover {
     background: #efefef;
 }
 .sf-select-ul li.selected {
    background: #508196;
    color: #fff;
 }
 .sf-select:focus, .sf-radio:focus, .sf-checkbox:focus, input[type="text"]:focus {
     border-color: #222;
 }
 .sf-select:hover {
 }
 .sf-radio:hover, .sf-checkbox:hover, input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="text"]:focus,      .sf-select:focus {
     background: #efefef;
}
.sf-radio.selected, .sf-radio.selected:focus, .sf-radio.selected:hover, .sf-checkbox.selected, .sf-checkbox.selected:focus .sf-checkbox.selected:hover {
    background: #9cb7c3;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.buttonish {
    display: block;
    font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 2.8em;
    color: #fff;
    background: #9cb7c3;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 480px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #508196;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #222;
}
```

Comment: I am actually making my own checkbox right now, but cannot get `$(this).toggleClass('active');` to work right. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/w8yuZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Think in boxes, how many boxes does a populated select seem to have when you look at it in a browser...

a **lot**, and they have lots of associated styles/scripts (background/colors,paddings, the functionality open/close etc.)

And actually you don't see anything of that in **your** code

So the code can only come from the **browser**

and browsers are **different**,  all answers are correct, don't try to style it, let a JavaScript replace the elements and functionality.

Comment: The only box a populated select have that is not specifically represented by html code is the dropdown button. The container is represented by the `<select>` tag, and each element in the dropdown is represented by a `<option>` tag. I don't understand why css standards has not taken the possibilities to define custom styling longer - both for select and checkbox/radio buttons.