# Form elements that aren't styleable

Tags: jquery, html, forms

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/SZSMP/1/) is the fiddle. I am making custom form elements that aren't styleable. I am wondering what form elements aren't styleable so I can create them a custom one.

Current JS/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ol').hide();
    $('#click').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('down');
        $('ol').toggle();
        $('.l').click(function () {
            var l = $(this).html();
            $('#click').html(l + ' &blacktriangledown;');
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='click'> &blacktriangledown;</div>
<div id='list'>
    <ol>
        <li class='l'>Hello</li>
        <li class='l'>Hola</li>
        <li class='l'>Bonjour</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

(This question is useful for people doing the same thing I am.)

Comment: This depends on browsers and other things, if you're looking for a list of what styles form elements will accept in what browsers etc. you should problably look up the different form elements on the browser vendors pages and compile your own list.

Comment: there are a lot of plugins doing this already... this http://uniformjs.com/ for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Form elements that are not completely syllable are:**

- input[type=checkbox]
- input[type=radio]
- input[type=file]
- input[type=color]
- input[type=date]
- input[type=datetime]
- input[type=datetime-local]
- input[type=time]
- input[type=month]
- input[type=week]
- select
- select[multiple]

**Form elements that require browser specific styling:**

- input[type=seach]
- input[type=number]

Also note, there are plugins and workarounds for styling/replacing all of these already, and they are pretty good. If you plan on replacing these, you need to remember keyboard controls and ARIA attributes for people with disabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the list. Sorry I'm so late, been watching the US Open. You watch it?

Comment: Afraid not.  If this answer is acceptable, please accept it as the answer so that this question will be marked as such.

Comment: what ones do you think are the easiest besides: checkbox, radio, or select?

Comment: Excluding number and search which can be styled by css via Brower specific selectors, File would probably be the next easiest as the others involved more complicated interfaces for choosing options/values

Comment: ok. i have read that you use `display: none` on the file input, and use a span over it. is that correct?

Comment: this is complicated for me because the span I am putting it in is not clicking and doing the default function. is there just a javascript function to open file browser?

Comment: I don't get it...seems supernatural to me (jk i just don't know how)

Comment: ok, this 'Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?' business is driving me mad. ciao